# C++ to VB.NET Conversion: Assignment Within Expressions

Tags: c++, vb.net

Am converting some C++ code to VB.NET and need to convert assignments within expressions.  Below are some C++ lines of code for which it's not clear what the converted results would be:

```
    i2 = 1 + (i1 = i + i)
    i4 = 1 + (i3 = n - i1)
    wr = (wtemp = wr) * wpr - wi * wpi + wr
    data(0) = (h1r = data(0)) + data(1)
    data(0) = c1 * ((h1r = data(0)) + data(1))
```

Would the first line translate to:

```
    If i2 = 1 Then i1 = i + i
```

?

Comment: The expression value of an assignment is the assigned value.  So simply lift the assignment out of the expression and move it up.  Rewrite to i1 = i + 1: i2 = i1 + 1

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Hans gave you the procedure - but just in case there's still any doubt about how to do this, your final result should be:

```
i1 = i + i
i2 = 1 + i1
i3 = n - i1
i4 = 1 + i3
wtemp = wr
wr = wtemp * wpr - wi * wpi + wr
h1r = data(0)
data(0) = h1r + data(1)
h1r = data(0)
data(0) = c1 * (h1r + data(1))
```

Comment: Yes, in addition to Hans' suggestion, this worked example helped as well.

Answer (score -3):

The code is already converted to VB.NET!

For example if you look at the following VB.NET code

```
    Dim i2 As Int16
    Dim i1 As Int16
    Dim i As Int16
    Dim data(0 To 1)

    i = 1
    i1 = 1
    i2 = 0

    i2 = 1 + (i1 = i + i)   'Same as your C++ code

    MsgBox(i2)
```

It will return 1. The code translates to 
i2 = 1 + (if i1= i+i)

Comment: `i2 = 1 + (true|false + i) 'Not as your C++ code` or `i2 = 1 + (-1|0 + i) 'Not as your C++ code`